# How to pass variable data between components in Vue js

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, components

Here I'm trying to pass the variable header_url data to my other vue pages. Since I also want to use this for push and post methods in the other vue script tags. I'm not sure how to do it? Since, I can only find examples with data been transferred between html tags.

```
    // Home.vue

<template>
    <div>
        Home
    <h2>logout</h2>
    <a v-bind:href="url">logout</a>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
    data: () => ({
    url:"https:..."
    
  })
}

var header_url = window.location.href;
if (header_url.length>100) {
   var token=window.location.href.match(/\#(?:id_token)\=([\S\s]*?)\&/)[1]; // eslint-disable-line
   console.log(token);
   
}

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

To pass data between two URLs in single page app, you need use [Vue Router](https://router.vuejs.org/)
and [Route Meta Fields](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/meta.html).

From the docs :

> Sometimes, you might want to attach arbitrary information to routes like transition names, who can access the route, etc. This can be achieved through the meta property which accepts an object of properties and can be accessed on the route location and navigation guards